# CSS background image on 100% div width

Tags: css

![this is the way it should look like][1]

I have no idea how to write CSS for the image that need to be in bcg or div, that will be aligned with right side of content and header. This image has to go from right side of content to left side of browser window.

Lets say browser window is 1900px wide and content is 1100px center aligned. 
Image is aligned with the right side of browser window.

I want to write it the way when you change width of browser window, image needs to stay right aligned and left part need to 'disappear' like when you do that with background image and change size of div.

No stretching of the image is aloud, as well as no horizontal scroll.

It need to look like this http://city.tolteam.com/2.html  - site will look like this http://city.tolteam.com/ac.jpg

Any help is appreciated. Thx.

Comment: oops! looks like you need to re-do your image.

Comment: `background-position: right top;`

Comment: I tried 100% div i tried to put it in a body with fixed position. I believe I have to calculate window size and according to size change position... Maybe it would be easiest way. http://city.tolteam.com/1.html if you have any CSS and not JS solution it would be great

Comment: Looks like you found the solution.  Could you please post it as an answer to your own question so others with similar questions can use it as a reference?

Comment: well I can not answer now as I am not allowed.. will do it later

Comment: Have you tried just setting the background-position to fixed?

Comment: To me it seems you can solve your issue with a combination of some thing like: parent div wrapper and overflow:hidden property.. not sure if you tried that already?

Comment: lol, didn't see the date :) you probably already figured this out :)

Answer (score -1):

Use 
`float:right; width:50%; /* or a fixed width if you dont want the image to shrink or stretch */`

Say like

```
float:right; width:400px; /* The actual image width */
```

Which would keep constant size all the time irregular of browser resizes.